# How to prevent NSWindow showing on launch of a storyboard app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I have an app on OS X 10.10 which uses a storyboard. I cannot figure out how to prevent the main window from showing at launch.

I have the 'Visible At Launch' checkbox on the window unchecked.

I looked at a backtrace...

```
2015-02-03 19:50:19.714 Itsycal2[20485:620948] -[MyApp showWindow:]: caller: 1   AppKit  0x00007fff8bee4724 NSApplicationMain + 1080
```

...and it seems that NSApplicationMain is calling -showWindow: on my window controller?

The only way I can prevent the window from showing at launch is by overriding -showWindow: and *not* calling super. But now I've gutted -showWindow: and I don't want that.

How do I prevent NSApplicationMain from calling -showWindow: at launch?

Answer (score 2):

Under the HIG, all mac apps are required to show a window when the user clicks on the app icon, unless there is already a window open — then that one will be brought to the front.

Your app *should* show a window when showWindow is called. But if you really don't w ant to, then overriding `showWindow:` to do nothing (don't call super) is the correct approach.

The app icon being clicked (or your app being launched in some other way) is triggering a `showWindow:` event to be sent down the responder chain. Your window controller is in the "responder chain" and has a `showWindow:` method so it will be executed.

Alternatively, move your window controller out of the responder chain. Is it the app delegate? Perhaps your app delegate shouldn't be a subclass of `NSWindowController`. Make it subclass `NSObject` instead, then it won't have a `showWindow:` method. You can still have it be a controller with some windows, even if it doesn't subclass `NSWindowController`.

You can't stop the event from being triggered. You can only choose to ignore it.

Comment: First, thanks for the fast and thoughtful reply. I can make a sample app using a Xib instead of a Storyboard, wire up an NSWindowController in the Xib, uncheck 'Visible At Launch' on the window and my app will launch without the window showing. The showWindow: method isn't automatically called. I can't get this in Storyboards.

Comment: In my storyboard app, the window controller is not the app delegate. It is the initial controller in the Main.storyboard.